# Using moment.js to check if local time is between 2 other time zones times

Tags: javascript, time, compare, momentjs, luxon

Similar questions have been asked but for whatever reason I just can't wrap my head around this. I want a user anywhere in the world to see whether a shop is open or closed on my site. The shop's hours are 8am-8pm M-F, and 8am-7pm Sat-Sun.

So basically the code needs to grab the users local time and compare that to the current time in CT, and see if the shop is open. This is made a bit more complicated by the fact that if its 7pmCT on Tuesday night, it could be Wednesday morning in a far eastern time zone, so now you need to compare the days too.

All the searching I did found bits and pieces of similar questions/answers but I just can't wrap my head around how to put it all together to come up with a solution. I started by trying this:

```
var currTimeTokyo = moment.tz(moment(), 'Asia/Tokyo').format();
var currTimeCT = moment.tz(moment(), 'America/Chicago').format();
console.log(currTimeTokyo);
console.log(currTimeCT);
```

and that gives:

```
2021-10-30T00:51:42+09:00
2021-10-29T10:51:42-05:00
```

Those are correct, but now how do I compare to today's open/closed hours? I need to check if the Tokyo time is between open and close in CT, but the open/close times change depending on what day it is, and Tokyo could be a different day from CT anyways. How would you account for all of that?

UPDATE: I found something that worked and posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know moment.js and I think it is already announced deprecated (day.js or luxon would be current alternatives) so I can't give you the proper syntax, but I try to help with the logic.

1. Like you said, take the current local time from the user
2. convert it to CTtime the shop is in. And if there's tuesday, then there's tuesday and depending on your shop hours it's closed or open. It doesn't matter if the timezone you're checking from might already have changed the day
3. compare the local time of the shop to the opening hours - which workday is it? Is it between opening and closing?

Comment: Thanks! I looked into Luxon and was able to come up with something I think works. I edited my original post with the new code. I think I was overthinking the day aspect of it, but by immediately converting the local time into CT that made the rest relatively simple. Maybe there was a way to do that in momentjs, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Happy to hear you found a solution with luxon, looks good! Instead of modifiying your question (which seems to be already answered) you could have wrote this in an answer instead and accept that. (you might still do this by rollback your edit and post new content in the answer)

Comment: Good call. Updated to reflect that!

Answer (score 0):

I looked into Luxon as Corrl suggested and I came up with this, which I think solves my problem.

```
// open hours are M-F 8am-8pm, Sat-Sun 8am-7pm (all times CT)
var hours = [ 
    { day: 'Sunday', open:8, close:19 },
    { day: 'Monday', open:8, close:20 },
    { day: 'Tuesday', open:8, close:20 }, 
    { day: 'Wednesday', open:8, close:20 },
    { day: 'Thursday', open:8, close:20 },
    { day: 'Friday', open:8, close:20 },
    { day: 'Saturday', open:8, close:19 }
];

var isOpen = false;
var local = luxon.DateTime.local(); // get current time in local tz
var localInCT = local.setZone("America/Chicago"); // rezone to CT without changing timestamp;

hours.forEach(function(item, index){
    if (index === localInCT.weekday && localInCT.hour >= item.open && localInCT.hour < item.close) {
        isOpen = true;
    }
});
console.log(isOpen);
```

Comment: I think logically that's fine. Is there a reason you're using 'var' instead of 'const/let'? One thing which might be improved I think is to instead of having the hours as array which is always iterated completely with .forEach() making instead either an object with weekday numbers as keys for lookup or checking for open via a function with a switch. [This example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-5ajnkr?file=script.js) shows what I mean.

Comment: Notice that according to the [luxon api docs](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimeweekday) the weekday numbers are from '1 = Monday' to '7 = Sunday'

Comment: @Corrl Using var because this is a fix for an ancient piece of code that can not use ES6. Believe me, it bothers me too. Also, thanks for the heads up on the index for weekdays. I just assumed it was the same as momentjs and used Sun=0 - Sat=6. Funny enough, only Sunday really has a different index between moment and luxon, but it changes everything when it comes to looping arrays and such. Thanks for the example, I think your solution using an object with a lookup key instead of an array makes more sense in this case!